# Weapon % damage bonus

Tags: borderlands

In Borderlands, I often see gun descriptions with things like +40% damage.

Is this percentage pre-applied when I look at the damage stat?  Or do I need to mentally add 40% to listed weapon damage when comparing weapons?

How about for rate-of-fire?
or reload speed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Bonuses that are listed on the weapon card are already included in the stats.

Bonuses you get from other places (like skills, proficiencies, etc.) are not, you'll have to do the math there.